# Locking the 'select' in update ... from select - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, locking

I have some inherited code with the following:

```
const sql = `UPDATE fqdn SET lock = $1
                    FROM (SELECT id FROM fqdn WHERE region = $2 AND lock IS NULL AND expires < $3 OR lock = $1 LIMIT $4) AS expired
                    WHERE fqdn.id = expired.id
                    RETURNING fqdn.id, fqdn.config, fqdn.data`;
```

There are multiple microservices running that query on the same DB.
The idea of the creator is to lock the batch of rows to be worked by each microservice with a lock field that is the fqdn ($1 => fqdn) of the machine where the microservice is running.

It looks like though that two microservices can end up working on the same batch sometimes.
Is there a way to serialize it so that a concurrent second thread only performs the select once the first has finished updating the lock?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a race condition in the query. Two concurrent executions could find the same row in the subquery, and while one of the updates will block, it will continue processing eventually, when the other transaction has completed.

You should add the following to the subquery:

```
FOR NO KEY UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

That would guarantee that no two queries can return the same rows.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz,
it looks like it works well